# How can I change my login method from GoogleID to something else?

Tags: support, bug, login, openid

Since quite some time I can access Stack Overflow from one single computer using the GoogleID cookie that was once created. When I try to login from another computer, this is not recognized, supposedly because some different data is being submitted. A Google login will only let me create a new Stack Exchange account.

I tried to add other logins in my profile, but everything there resulted in a "Page not found" error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: PS: This is my read-only profile I created using the same GoogleID: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4740051/thomas-mielke

Comment: Simple: 1. Create new login. 2. Use it. 3, Optionally delete old login. - - All is on the third page of your profile.

Comment: I log into the site from 3 different machines using the same google id without any problems.  Maybe your latest login attempt is using a valid google id but for a different google account (e.g. you signed into another email account prior to attempting to login).

Comment: @Deduplicator: Sure... Profile -> Settings -> My Logins -> Add more logins... that's where I picked the screenshots from.

Comment: @rasteve: The problem is that I logged in using an old email address to get the session key but at some point google forced me to change my email addres to a gmail.com account. Ever since, I wasn't able to login from elsewhere. So it's not actually two accounts.

Comment: Re the page not found issue: If you try to add a login from Meta, you get a page not found. If you go to your _main_ profile and try to add logins, it's fine.

Comment: See this answer on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704

Answer (score 1):

I'ts no good solution: I added a Facebook login and was able to connect to my active Stack account this way. I really hate using Facebook for this...

Edit: Kendra gave a very useful hint... "If you try to add a login from Meta, you get a page not found. If you go to your main profile and try to add logins, it's fine."